# DialogFragment with custom View alwas takes full screen width

Tags: android

I use `DialogFragment` with custom `View` populated from XML and standard buttons from `AlertDialog.Builder`. My `onCreateDialog` looks as follows:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolkit_picker_color, null);
    setupView(rootView);

    builder.setView(rootView);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, this);
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, this);

    return builder.create();
}
```

With layout of custom View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/toolkit.container.a"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <include layout="@layout/toolkit_picker_color_modes" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When dialog is displayed, its height, as expected, wraps the content of the custom layout. However, the width of the dialog takes whole screen, as if `match_parent` has been used.

I have seen solutions based on setting dialog's width from source code, but this is not what I am looking for, and it does not work with `WRAP_CONTENT`.

There is no problem when using `DialogFragment` without `AlertDialog.Builder`. However, I need those buttons.

Is there a way to set width of `DialogFragment` utilizing`AlertDialog.Builder` to `wrap_content`, based on its custom `View`?

Comment: I am not sure how `wrap_content`, `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`and `android:gravity="center"` interact. Can you try leaving out some of them and iterate over all  combinations?

Comment: @mcwise I have tried not using `AlertDialog.Builder.setView` at all, leaving only buttons, or even without them, using only `AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage` - same result. Therefore, I think it is not issue with layout itself.